# Browser POST/PUT to soapUI as rest service

Tags: rest, soapui

I wanted to mock **get**, **post** and **put**. I was able to configure get which run on the SoapUI server. So whenever I call the url I am getting the JSON value which I set in response with media type application/json.

Same way wanted to mock a **POST** and **PUT**. The client will use th URL and post some data. I want to check if the data is received properly in SoapUI. How can we do this?

Comment: What is a "SoapUI server"?

Comment: soapui comes with an in build http server. You can run your mock service in that server, you can configure the port as well.

Comment: So you are trying to mock a REST service? Have you tried the documentation? http://www.soapui.org/rest-testing-mocking/rest-service-mocking.html

Comment: I have tried this and when ever I call post I am getting the response. But i want to make sure if the data i have posted to this mock is the same which i gave from ui or callie. How can i see the data which is posted to this mockservice?

Comment: Use the `log.info ...` method.

Comment: Ok thats new to me. Any link to complete script?

Comment: Again!!! Documentation: http://www.soapui.org/rest-testing-mocking/mock-service-scripting.html

Comment: This answers my question.. If you could answer rather than comment i will accept it.

Comment: Link-only answers are considered off-topic on SO, and the moderators would eventually deleted such an answer. See [answer].